# Laravel 5.6 login change Hash::make($data['password']) to

Tags: php, laravel, joomla

I have to use an old user database for our new Laravel 5.6 website.  There is now way I can ask all the users to remake passwords.  The old site was joomla 3.7.5 and after a bit of playing around I found that,  check password on login Joomla 3.7.5 used...

```
$result = password_verify($PlanTextLoginForm, $PasswordForDB);
```

and to make a new user's password...

```
$PasswordForDB = password_hash($PlanTextLoginForm, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

I have found about 6 places in Laravel to change...

```
Hash::make($data['password']) 
to
password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

I just can't find the login challenge?

nothing in the LoginController.

So the real question is where is the login-> function found for Auth::routes(); ?

Comment: Most important is to edit the factory one and not make a new one.  I don't want to miss all the other security the factory one has to offer.

Comment: You shouldn't even need to change anything, Laravel uses bcrypt too.

Comment: Hi Devon, I was hoping this was true.  No luck I get a Fail on login.

Comment: Ok, it should.  You can look at the BcryptHasher class to see the default hash implementation and use Hash::check just like password_verify.  You should not hard code password_verify in Laravel, plug in your own hash implementation.

Comment: Please do not add "solved" in a question title, thank you. Also, you may read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262123/automatically-remove-solved-from-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel basic authentication function

```
public function postLogin()
{
   $rules = array(
'email'    => 'required|email', 
'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:6');

 $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if ($validator->fails()) 
{
    return Redirect::to('login')
    ->withErrors($validator) 
    ->withInput(Input::except('password')); 
} 
else
{
    $userdata = array(
    'email'     => Input::get('email'),
    'password'  => Input::get('password')
    );
   if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) 
   {

    return Redirect::to('dashboard');

    } 
    else
   {        
     return Redirect::to('login');
   }

  }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, so where is this kept.  I see it is looking at... \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.  As posted above...

You shouldn't even need to change anything, Laravel uses bcrypt too. – Devon

Jwt-auth package changes the password encryption of the passwords.

Comment: Typing **SOLVED** into your question's title is not the way that StackOverflow pages are marked as resolved.  If someone's answer solved your issue, you should mark their answer with a green tick.  [Accepting your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) is perfectly acceptable too. "As posted above" isn't reliable terminology because your answer's placement may change over time; instead, please type out the solution as eloquently / educationally as possible for the benefit of future researchers.